# Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 SSL Certificate Install

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, encryption

I have been tasked with installing an SSL certificate on an Apache Tomcat server (version 7.0.35). This is not something I have had any experience with before so hoping for a little guidance! The notes I have found online seem only to cover new installations.

Looking at the `server.xml` file I can see that there are existing SSL certificates on there as well as keystore configurations.

Please could any one advise me what the process is for generating and adding a new SSL certificate when there are already some present in `server.xml`? For example do I need to remove the existing instances or can I just add a new one, are further changes needed to the keystore file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Go to bin folder in server
Run the command 
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048

then

keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks


In conf\server.xml edit it as

//...
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
        This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
        connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
        described in the APR documentation -->

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
              maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="my key store file path"
           keystorePass="password" />
 //...
```

keystorePass="password" is the password you assigned to your keystore via “keytool” command.

[image]

[image]

Then hit URL https://localhost:8443/

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Abhijit, how would I add a certificate that has been provided in .pfx format. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes its possible and this works for you then please give me a tick ... 
just use extension as .pfx instead of .jks

Comment: Thanks for explaining Abhijit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add SSL certificates to keystore
   $openssl pkcs12 -export -out biosit.pfx -inkey biosit.ebsafrica.com.key -in biosit.ebsafrica.com.cer
2. Confirm certicate was successfully added to keystore
   $keytool -list -keystore equitybio.pfx -v
3. add keystoreFile path to server.xml and specify the keystorePass
4. uncomment   in web.xml
5. restart tomcat
6. Change your browser url from http to https
7. You are now secure

reference:  https://www.ssl.com/how-to/create-a-pfx-p12-certificate-file-using-openssl/